# Getting only specific pattern using locate

Tags: command-line, tar, regex

I tried:

```
$ locate 'tar' | head -2
/bin/tar
/bin/unicode_start
```

How I can get rid of this 'unicode_start'?

Comment: Try `locate -b '\tar'

Comment: Without that first quote, sry - `locate -b '\tar'`

Comment: Why don't you use `which` instead?